# Expose Kafka-properties to Sprong Cloud DataFlow UI

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-dataflow

In SpringBoot-application, which have been deployed in Stream, I use properties in yaml-file:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      retries: 8
```

Is it possible to show and manage this properties in UI of Spring Cloud DataFlow, like this:

[image: deployment]

Answer (score 0):

The binder specific properties are not **currently** exposed as Spring Cloud Data Flow isn't aware of (doesn't need to be aware of) the underlying middleware in use.